# Ignore symbolic links when listing file paths in a folder

Tags: vb.net, list, exception, hyperlink, path

How can I ignore symbolic links when listing file paths in a folder? They throw an Access Denied exception.

I'm using this code:

`IO.Directory.GetFiles(PATH, "*.*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)`

thanks.

Comment: Maybe you just don't have read access to a subfolder. Your best bet is to search each folder individually.

Comment: No, it's caused by a symbolic link.

Comment: Have you tried searching each individual folder instead of doing a AllDirectories?